# Cannot add foreign key constraignt MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

I am creating a database in MySQL for school. It has come up with the error 'cannot add foreign key constraint.' I have looked at other similar questions but cannot find out how it relates to my table. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Update your `entries` table like so:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
entry_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
exam_date DATE NOT NULL,
student_id INT REFERENCES students(student_id),
subject_id INT REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
PRIMARY KEY(entry_id)
)
```