# MySQL won't let me add multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

So I'm working on a project in school in which we use MySQL to make a database and complete various tasks about school subjects and exam boards. One of my questions was to:

"Create and populate a third table called *entries*, again using query scripts. This table should contain foreign keys to allow sensible links to be made with the other two tables, together with the dates of each exam."

When carrying out this task I tried this code out

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(

subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),

FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id)

);
```

And that worked fine, but when I tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(

subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,

level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),

FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),

FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subjects(subject_name)

);
```

It threw up and error message stating:

```
"ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint"
```

Any clues on how to add multiple foreign key statements without it causing an error. Also I did try using the ALTER TABLE function and that didn't work,

Many thanks

Andrew.

Comment: Are you trying to create the same table twice?

Comment: I assume that subject name is no PK in the table subjects. That could be a problem.

Comment: Got it sorted now thanks, just randomly fixed itself when I created a new file

Comment: I'm not sure how it randomly fixed itself.  A foreign key is different than a denormalized column.  A foreign key is an identifier that migrates from a source table into a target table to enable the tables to be joined.  A denormalized value is simply one that is copied from one table into another and cannot EVER be counted on to join against.

Comment: Neither am I, I changed the name of the file and saved it again as an .sql file and it fixed

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863550/cannot-add-foreign-key-constraignt-mysql