# Field "subject_name" doesn't have a default value

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, field

This is a follow up to a previous question I have put up linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36478190/mysql-wont-let-me-add-multiple-foreign-keys)

And that issue is sorted now, but now another one appears when I attempt to set a date time for an exam. This happens.

Error 1364 (HY000): Field 'subject name' doesn't have a default value"

For someone relatively new to MySQL, I have no clue how to fix this error and any help would be great.

Thanks in advance

Andrew

**EDITED**

Here is the table I created and tried to use.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(
subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
subject_name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id),
FOREIGN KEY (subject_name) REFERENCES subjects(subject_name),
FOREIGN KEY (level_of_entry) REFERENCES subjects(level_of_entry),
FOREIGN KEY (exam_board) REFERENCES subjects(exam_board)
);
```

Comment: Please post your table create statement.

Comment: subject_name is a poor choice for an FK. Stick with subject_id.

Comment: Remove the last 3 lines (and the comma)

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS entries(

subject_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

subject_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',

level_of_entry VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

exam_board VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,

date_of_exam DATETIME NOT NULL,

PRIMARY KEY (date_of_exam),

FOREIGN KEY (subject_id) REFERENCES subjects(subject_id)

);
```

Comment: What could I do to add more foreign keys? I seem to be able to only add one, and when I use the ALTER function to try and add it it comes up with an error saying it can't add foreign keys?

Answer (score 0):

Is this error occurring during the table creation or when you insert data into the table?

If this error occurs when you insert data into the table, probably is because you are inserting a null value into the field `subject_name`. Given this is a foreing key you should check if `subjects` table does not have null values on this field.